# Ordering the results randomly not working in pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working in WordPress and I am trying to order the product results randomly. Like every time a customer refresh the page then the products should be randomly shown. Currently no matter how many times I refresh the page.

Each time products are showing in the same order. The first product will be at first and last will be at last.

I am writing this query

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rand_products');

function rand_products( $query) {
  
    //if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->query['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $query->query['order'] = 'rand';
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand');
        $query->set( 'order', 'rand' );
    /}
}
```

If I see the query dump(attached in the screenshot) then I can see that query parameters have been changed but Still it is not working. Can anyone Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The troubleshoot might be coming from the fact that you're using an undefined value for the `order` parameter.

As per the `WP_Query` order & order by parameters:

| Parameters | Values |
| --- | --- |
| `order (string | array)` - Designates the ascending or descending order of the ‘orderby‘ parameter. Defaults to `DESC`. An array can be used for multiple order/orderby sets. | `ASC` - ascending order from lowest to highest values (1, 2, 3; a, b, c). |
|  | `DESC` - descending order from highest to lowest values (3, 2, 1; c, b, a). |
| `orderby (string | array)` - Sort retrieved posts by parameter. Defaults to `date (post_date)`. One or more options can be passed. | `rand` - Random order. |

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

As you can see only `orderby` can take a `rand` value. `order` should be set to either `DESC` descending order or `ASC` ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is worked. I had check in my local.
I have one suggestion for this, any used theme or installed plugine may be conflict for this code.
Add Priority

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','pre_get_posts', 999 );
```

Comment: Default priority never need to be changed. It's considered bad practice.

Comment: @Team Dolphin I have added priority but not working